# How to compare a HashMap and Arraylist to find similar values

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm using this [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/El0MN.jpg)  to compare two sets of values: a `HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>>` and the other `ArrayList<Integer>`. The goal of the program is to compare each value in the HashMap, with the values in the ArrayList, and returns a new HashMap of the similar values. So far, my program runs normally, but it returns false results.

**ArrayList Example**

[1.0.1.0.0]

**HashMap Example**

1. [1.0.1.1.0]
2. [0.1.1.0.0]
3. [0.1.1.1.0]

**Result:**

1. 4
2. 3
3. 2

**My Program**

```
int k = 1;
List<Integer> listOperateur = new ArrayList<Integer>();
HashMap<Integer, Integer> sim = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
    count = 0;

    for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {
        if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k))) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
    k++;

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the program give a wrong result in newhashmap

Comment: I don't quite understand what that means.

Comment: The counter 'count ' does not count correctemet, it gives wrong result, i don't know where is the problem in loop for

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose the problem if we knew exactly what you're trying to achieve.  You said you wanted to compare each value in the `Map` with a value in the `List`, but I don't understand what that means.

Comment: yes i want this, i want comapre value in Map whit a value in list, if are similaire count ++ ,And move to the next item in Map and Arraylist, check if are similaire..To the end

Comment: Tried to improve the formatting so it is a little easier to read.

Comment: @Leigh I solved my problem
 thnks

Comment: @FzKaddour - Glad you figured it out. So what actually fixed the issue? (I cannot tell from the code alone). Consider adding a brief explanation to your "answer" to help others that run into a similar problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're attempting to rely on the insertion order of objects into the `HashMap` which is not wise, as order is not preserved.  Instead, try changing `hmm`'s type from `HashMap` to `LinkedHashMap` and see if that solves your problem.

Edit: Also, you should probably initialize `k` to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: It gives me the same result

Comment: @FzKaddour Can you post all of your updated code in the OP?  Including where you initialize and add elements to `hmm`.

Comment: I posted it now

Comment: @FzKaddour Now it seems that you have another `Map` named `hm`.  Try making that a `LinkedHashMap` as well.  If it doesn't fix your issue, then I must not understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have already tried and it gives me the same result thnk u for yout help

Comment: I added a picture to better understand

Answer (score 1):

```
 System.out.println("HASHMAP RESULT:");
    LinkedHashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hmm = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Entry<Integer, List<String>> ee : hm.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = ee.getKey();

        List<String> values = ee.getValue();
        List<Integer> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String temp : global) {

            list5.add(values.contains(temp) ? 1 : 0);

        }
        hmm.put(key, (ArrayList<Integer>) list5);

    }

    //nouvelle list operateur
    List<Integer> list6 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("liste operateur");
    List<Integer> listOperateur = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOperateur.add(1);
    listOperateur.add(0);
    listOperateur.add(0);
    listOperateur.add(0);
    Iterator iter = listOperateur.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
    }
    //calcule similarité

    System.out.println("HASHMAP SIMILIRATE RESULT:");
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> sim = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int count;
    int k = 0;


    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
        //if (e.getValue() != null) {
        count = 0;
        //you can move this part to another method to avoid deep nested code
        for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {

            if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k))) {
                count++;

            }
        }
        sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
        k++;

    }
```